# Присвоение переменной типа bool

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, num, factor;
            bool isprime;

            for (num = 2; num < 10; num ++)
            {
                isprime = true;
                factor = 0;

                for (i=2; i <= num/2; i++)
                {
                    if ((num % i) == 0)
                    {
                        isprime = false;
                        factor = i;
                    }
                }
                if (isprime)
                    Console.WriteLine(num + " - простое число");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Наибольший множитель числа " + num + " равен " + factor);
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Сразу скажу, что код рабочий. Программа получает число `num`, делит его на `i`, согласно условию и выводит на экран, что число `num`:

1. Простое число
2. Наибольший множитель числа `num` равен `i`

Теперь вопрос: почему значение `isprime` сначала принимается `true`, потом `false` и в операторе `if` берется значение `true`, хотя (если брать число 2) получается, что в последний оператор `if` входит `isprime=false`? Я запутался.

Comment: @Treaq, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Элементарно. Собственно, флаг isprime определяет, является ли число простым. Сначала, на каждой новой итерации цикла вы допускаете, что очередное число является простым (**isprime = true**). Затем, если ваше число без остатка делится на i, то число, разумеется уже нельзя считать простым (**isprime = false**).

Answer (score 3):

У Вас в начале цикла присвоение переменной isprime значения true. При входе во второй цикл, естественно, значение true.

В первой итерации переменная i = num = 2, и вы без остатка делите num / i, значение isprime становится равно false.

Во второй итерации переменная i равна 3, и Вы делите 2 / 3, получая остаток не равный нулю.